# java concurrent map sorted by value

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap, sortedmap, concurrentskiplistmap

I'm looking for a way to have a concurrent map or similar key->value storage that can be sorted by value and not by key.

So far I was looking at [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) but I couldn't find a way to sort it by value (using [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)), since `compare` method receives only the keys as parameters.

The map has keys as String and values as Integer. What I'm looking is a way to retrieve the key with the smallest value(integer).

I was also thinking about using 2 maps, and create a separate map with Integer keys and String values and in this way I will have a sorted map by integer as I wanted, however there can be more than one integers with the same value, which could lead me into more problems.

Example

"user1"=>3
"user2"=>1
"user3"=>3

sorted list: 
"user2"=>1
"user1"=>3
"user3"=>3

Is there a way to do this or are any 3rd party libraries that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To sort by value where you can have multiple "value" to "key" mapping, you need a [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). This needs to be synchronized as there is no concurrent version.

This doesn't meant the performance will be poor as that depends on how often you call this data structure. e.g. it could add up to 1 micro-second.

Comment: hi thanks, but I don't think I need a multimap since the key(String)->value(integer) is unique , and I can't have the same key with 2 values, but I want my map to be sorted by value(integer) or I was thinking but this also not working to inverse the map and use the Integer as key and String as value however this can lead to having multiple keys with same value(integer) see I've update the exampe

Comment: So if you have multiple keys to the same value and you invert it you need a MultiMap because now you have one key with multiple values. In short, you can only sort by the key.

Comment: yea... you're right, however I want to be able to delete at some time an entry based on the key(String). By inverting the map, I think this will be a little harder to do since I have to do a search by the value.

Comment: If you have an inverted map you don't need to search for it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do this and ended up using a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` where the keys contain a string and an integer. I ended up using the answer proposed below. The core insight is that you can structure your code to allow for a duplicate of a key with a different value before removing the previous one.

[Atomic way to reorder keys in a ConcurrentSkipListMap / ConcurrentSkipListSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15507418/586086)

The problem was to keep a dynamic set of strings which were associated with integers that could change concurrently from different threads, described below. It sounds very similar to what you wanted to do.

[Is there an embeddable Java alternative to Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14805852/586086)

Here's the code for my implementation:

https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/TurkServer/blob/master/turkserver/src/main/java/edu/harvard/econcs/turkserver/util/UserItemMatcher.java

Answer (score 0):

The principle of a `ConcurrentMap` is that it can be accessed concurrently - if you want it sorted at any time, performance will suffer significantly as that map would need to be fully synchronized (like a hashtable), resulting in poor throughput.

So I think your best bet is to return a sorted view of your map by putting all elements in an unmodifiable TreeMap for example (although sorting a TreeMap by values needs a bit of tweaking).

Comment: values in my map are constantly changing by adding/deleting keys or by changing the values

Comment: Do you really need it sorted at any time or do you only need to query the key with the smallest value from time to time?

Comment: actually I only need to retrieve the smallest value from time to time, I don't care if it's sorted or not. Is there a way to do this without parsing the entire map?

Comment: Nope, but that's the only solution I can think of in general -- it's not an issue of what Java does or doesn't provide, it's an issue of what's doable in general.