# Atomic way to reorder keys in a ConcurrentSkipListMap / ConcurrentSkipListSet?

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrency, sortedmap, concurrentskiplistmap

Summary of this post: I have an set of ordered items whose order may change over time. I need to be able to iterate through this set from multiple threads, each of which may also want to update the order of the items.

For example, multiple threads need to access `String` keys in some arbitrary sorted order. They strings are not sorted according to their natural ordering, but by some values that may change (hence, a custom `Comparator`). My original implementation was to use a `TreeSet` and synchronize on it. If any of the keys needed to be reordered, a thread would remove the key from the map, update the comparison value, and reinsert the key. To implement this, the keys are native `String`s, but the comparator has access to the values. This is a weird arrangement where the order of keys may change over time, but since a changed key is always removed and reinserted when it changes, it seems to work. (I suppose it could also work if the `String`s were wrapped inside another object.)

I recently became aware of the `ConcurrentSkipListSet`/`ConcurrentSkipListMap` implementations which are basically thread-safe sorted sets (resp. maps.) It seems like I can now iterate through the keys without having to lock the entire data structure. However, is there a way I can use them to atomically remove a key and replace it with another, like the operation I was doing above, so that other iterating threads don't miss the item, and without having to use `synchronize` blocks?

If anyone can suggest a better data structure for this type of operation, I'm all ears, too!

Comment: This design would make me really nervous.  Comparators shouldn't change over time.

Comment: What would you suggest for something that needs to maintain a set of objects whose order may change over time?

Comment: A List that gets sorted with new comparators each time, probably, or alternatively, I'd edit my StackOverflow question to give us more details about the problem that makes you want such a data structure. ;)

Comment: This is why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805852/is-there-an-embeddable-java-alternative-to-redis. Currently I'm just building a pure-java version.

Comment: In that answer, why do you care if it is out of the list for some ~Xms?  If it sorts lower then fine.  If it doesn't then fine.  I don't see why it _has_ to be always in the list.  Removing it from the list also helps you not have to synchronize on the object itself.  If you aren't removing it from the list to work on it, how do you stop ++ race conditions between threads?

Comment: And are you really sure that removing something from the skip list and re-adding inside of a synchronized block is a performance problem?  Is this premature optimization?

Comment: I have an edge case where there is only one item in the list and threads that attempt to iterate through the list see an empty list. What do I do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way I can use them to atomically remove a key and replace it with another, like the operation I was doing above, so that other iterating threads don't miss the item, and without having to use synchronize blocks?

The short answer is no.  If you need to remove and reinsert, there is no atomic way to do this with any collection that I know of.

That said, one possibility would be for you to reinsert the item *before* deleting it from the skip list.  This would cause a duplicate but may be easier to handle then a missing entry.  You would reinsert it after you changed the object so it would sort differently.  This assumes that the object would then be non-equal as well.  But if the other threads that are processing the lists can't handle the duplicates then I think you are SOL.